# C++ for loop exercise

Tags: c++, for-loop

Below you can find a basic C++ exercise with a for loop, the question is: what is the value of i after the loop runs. (Apparently, the value is 5.)

My question, on the 5th run (i=5), the value of a is 100, shouldn't the loop stop since the condition is a<100? Isn't the condition checked after a is multiplied with 10? (so after a is already 100)

If I check the value of a after the loop exit, it will be 1000. I am confused. Why does the loop not stop at 100?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    float a;
    int i = 0;
    for(a = 0.01; a < 1e2; a *= 1e1)
        ++i;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: fixed it now thanks.

Comment: Start by using consistent types: `a` is `float`, while all those literals are `double`.

Comment: I did not write the code, it was an exercise for the C++ basic certification.

Comment: `for ( a = 0.01...` and I knew what it was all about. That's what we call a "code smell": You *might* know what you're doing when using floating points in loops, but chances are you don't. ;-)

Comment: @Laurentiu Use `cout<<setprecision(9)<<a<<endl;` and you'll get the answer. (`#include <iomanip>`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exercise is designed to show that `float` (and `double` etc., floating point numbers in general) do **not** have the exact decimal value as what you see in the program text.

`0.01` (decimal) cannot be exactly represented in the binary floating point format used, therefore multiplying 10 five times will not yield exactly `100.0`.

See also: [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell exactly what will happen with this code without knowing the details of the floating point implementation on your platform; the C++ standard leaves this intentionally flexible.

In essence `0.01` could be an approximation for the closest `float` to that `double` literal. So the stopping conditional `a < 1e2` could be met prematurely or otherwise.

Note that along with `0.01`, `1e1` is a literal of type `double`.

So the conversions to `float` are complicating things further. Then there is floating point *strictness* to consider.

Cut a long story short: *don't* use a floating point as the "index" in a loop.